# Job replies with link back to job

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Would be great if the reply e-mail from a job included a link to show the job that you replied to.

A lot of times I send my resume out to many job postings, so when they reply, I'd love to be able to quickly click a link and see the job posting that they are associated with, in the e-mail and in the reply to message section.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:**

These emails now include a link to the job. They are also [way prettier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qSLG.png) than [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO3rp.png).

**Original answer:**

This is actually a feature that is already planned.

Right now we have a lot of important tasks on our plate, and I cannot guarantee when exactly it will happen, but it will!

Comment: Instead of those long sentences, you could have just written *In 6-8 weeks* :-(